# Carrierwave and Jcrop not cropping with Minimagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, jcrop

I'm following Ryan Bates tutorial on how to crop images with Carrierwave and Jcrop.

But, images are not being cropped. x,y,w,h values are being passed in parameters, but no cropping is taking place. Im using Minimagick. I will really appreciate help from someone.

I've followed similar issues in Stackoverflow but none give a good solution.
Thank you

**Photo_uploader**

```
  process :resize_to_fit => [800,800]

  version :big do
    process :resize_to_limit => [800,600]
    process :convert => 'jpg'
  end

  version :thumb, :from_version => :big do
    process :crop
    resize_to_fill(100,100)
  end

  def crop
    if model.crop_x.present?
      resize_to_limit(600, 600)
      manipulate! do |img|
        x = model.crop_x.to_i
        y = model.crop_y.to_i
        w = model.crop_w.to_i
        h = model.crop_h.to_i
        img.crop "#{model.crop_x}x#{model.crop_y}+#{model.crop_w}+#{model.crop_h}"
        img
      end
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
<%= image_tag @photo.photo_url(:big), id: "cropbox" %>
```

**Model**

```
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
  attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
  before_create :crop_spot
  after_update :crop_spot
```

**Update**

```
#Cropping spots
def crop_spot
  photo.recreate_versions! if crop_x.present?
end
```

Comment: Where is your crop_spot method?  Can you post that please

Comment: Are the crop text fields being set by the javascrpt?

Comment: @Baloo sorry , I hadn't seen your response. Yes, the values are being set. I still don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `img.crop` method does not change the image, but returns a new one. So either use `img.crop!`, which edits the image in place, or remove the last `img`, so that the edited image is retured.

The `crop` method then becomes

```
def crop
  if model.crop_x.present?
    resize_to_limit(600, 600)
    manipulate! do |img|
      x = model.crop_x.to_i
      y = model.crop_y.to_i
      w = model.crop_w.to_i
      h = model.crop_h.to_i
      img.crop "#{model.crop_x}x#{model.crop_y}+#{model.crop_w}+#{model.crop_h}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: img.crop! is for Rmagick.  img.crop is for MiniMagick.  The docs indicate that crop expects WxH+X+Y

Answer (score 0):

For me it works like that:

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fit => [Cover::IMAGE_WIDTH, -1] # '-1' means that height is infinite (this is works for minimagick, but for rmagick it should be '10000').
  process :manual_crop
  process :resize_to_fill => [340, 191]
end

version :big do
  process :resize_to_fit => [Cover::IMAGE_WIDTH, -1]
  process :manual_crop
  process :resize_to_fill => [Cover::IMAGE_WIDTH, Cover::IMAGE_HEIGHT]
end

def manual_crop
  return if model.crop_coords.blank?
  manipulate! do |img|
    img.crop "#{model.crop_coords['w'].to_i}x#{model.crop_coords['h'].to_i}+#{model.crop_coords['x'].to_i}+#{model.crop_coords['y'].to_i}!"
    img
  end
end
```

crop_coords is coordinates returned by JCrop (but we don't need x2 and y2, so I don't use them here)
Take into consideration that format is "WxH+X+Y".
Refer to http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry and http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop